# Retrieve generic trait parameter on concrete inheritor via macro

Tags: scala, generics, macros

I have a simple subtyping relation that I've set up as follows:

```
trait Foo[T] {
    def a: Int
    def b: String
    def c: T
}

object Bar extends Foo[C] { /* implementation */ }
object Quux extends Foo[D] { /* implementation */ }
// ...
```

where `C` and `D` are concrete types. I also have a manager object that registers objects of type `Foo[T]` and needs to maintain generic type information in order to correctly call method `c`.

The scala compiler seems incapable of correctly inferring types here for my manager's `register` method, so I need to specify that manually. I.e., I can't do

```
Manager register Bar
```

but instead have to provide

```
Manager register[C, Bar.type] Bar
```

To make this a bit prettier, I'm writing a macro that does this automatically, but I'm stuck on retrieving the concrete type parameter of the trait the object inherits from. The basic form of the macro looks like this:

```
def macro_impl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: whitebox.Context)(a: c.Expr[T]): c.Expr[Unit] = {
     import c.universe._
     val typeIWant = weakTypeOf[T].???
     c.Expr[Unit](q"com.example.Manager.register[${a.actualType}, ${typeIWant}]($a)")
}
```

I've been able to retrieve the list of supertypes of `T`, but I haven't been able to figure out how to get the type parameter for those types *within* the object declaration, i.e. I'm looking for `U` here: `object ... extends Foo[U]`). Is there a way to do this?

**Edit:** I can get the type information I want to show up in the console via reflection:

```
scala> typeOf[Bar].typeSymbol.info
res1: reflect.runtime.universe.Type =
com.example.Foo[com.example.C] {
  def <init>(): com.example.Bar
  def a: scala.Int
  def b: String
  def c(event: com.example.C): scala.Unit
}
```

but I'm still not sure how to get information about the `com.example.Foo[com.example.C]` part of the signature. Not finding anything pertinent in the reflection API docs (particularly `TypeApi`) about how to do this.

Comment: What does the `register` method itself look like?

Comment: The signature is `def register[T <: Baz: TypeTag, U <: Foo[T]](elem: U): Unit`, where `Baz` is just a common supertype of these concrete types (which are declared as case classes).

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use `def register[F[X] <: Foo[X], T <: Baz: TypeTag](elem: F[T]): Unit`

Comment: Nope, that solves my problem (if I specify `F[X <: T]`); thanks! I still would like to know how to get the type information I'm looking for though, as I've run into this situation a couple times before.